# $ Command not found with "rails new app -m myfile.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, command-line

I'm trying to use the [MongoID-Devise generator template](https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/master/rails3-mongoid-devise-template.rb) by doing this under Ubuntu and using RVM:

```
rails new myapp -m https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/raw/master/rails3-mongoid-devise-template.rb
```

I've also tried to download the file and do the generation locally, but in both cases, I get:

```
$: command not found
```

As according to the guides: [Application Template](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), I'm using the command/options correctly...

**EDIT**:

The following commands gives me the following results:

```
rails -v --> Rails 3.1.3
ruby -v --> ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Just a note: You need the " -T -O" flags on the end of the command string as detailed in the readme. Use the -T -O flags to skip Test::Unit files and Active Record files.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that's not what is causing the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "$" you see at the beginning of the command is actually a convention that indicates a Unix console prompt. Don't include the "$".

Comment: I haven't included that.. THat's the output that gives me when trying doing the rails new app.

Comment: The "rails new myapp -m ..." command works here for me and no one else has reported an error. I'm able to duplicate your error by entering "$ rails new myapp -m ...". Not sure what else it may be. Are you still seeing the error?

Comment: I had a conflict in the RVM it seems. Reinstalled RVM, launched again and succeed. Thanks